# How to retrieve dynamically created label control from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the buttons and label boxes that are dynamically created in Grid view Template page, this is done in C#. On page load, only the buttons are visible.  When a button is clicked, I want the respective label to change its visibility to true.

I am unable to retrieve the control in the Gridview OnRowCommand. I already declared the following:

```
lblAvailone = (Label)row.FindControl("lblFirstAvail");
```

Could you please tell me how I can get that label value in row command?

Comment: can you show some more code? your gridview in .aspx and .cs ?

Comment: When you click the button and postback occurs - do you recreate the GridView - including dynamic labels? Dynamic controls have to be recreated on every postback.